# TPU training fails with certain metric, succeeds on CPU

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I'm trying to train a simple EfficientNet style model on some images. Training works fine on a CPU, but when I switch across to using a TPU I get the following error:

> (0) Invalid argument: {{function_node
> __inference_train_function_38255}} Output shapes of then and else branches do not match: (s64[1,<=4]) vs. (s64[<=4])
>
> [[{{node cond}}]]
> [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_5430787790498024493/_4]]
> [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_6318656678166656164/_5/_289]]
>
> (1) Invalid argument: {{function_node
> __inference_train_function_38255}} Output shapes of then and else branches do not match: (s64[1,<=4]) vs. (s64[<=4])
>
> [[{{node cond}}]]
> [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_5430787790498024493/_4]]
> [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_6318656678166656164/_5/_225]]

This error only occurs when I'm using a particular metric, [Cohen's Kappa](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/CohenKappa). If I remove this metric, the model trains fine.

I've tried to figure out the offending section in CohensKappa and narrowed it down to `_update_confusion_matrix` - if I overload this and `result`, the model trains fine.

When I start training, I see this log message:

> TPU has inputs with dynamic shapes: [<tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=()  dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'cond_8/Identity:0' shape=(None, 456, 456, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'cond_8/Identity_1:0' shape=(None,)  dtype=int64>]

Which may be related, however given that the model trains fine when I leave out this metric and I still get that log, it might be a red herring.

Any suggestions on solutions, or how to debug this would be very helpful. Switching to eager execution mode isn't an option, as it all works fine on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code snippet that leads to this error. From what it shows, you seem to have tensor dimension inconsistency problem (i.e. `(s64[1,<=4]) vs. (s64[<=4])`)